# Cannot read outlook profile using passport-outlook strategy with nestjs

Tags: passport.js, nestjs

Always getting the following error while using passport-outlook strategy with scopes `scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access']`

In the nest middleware,

```
consumer.apply(authenticate('outlook', {
      session: false,
      accessType: 'offline',
      scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
      callbackURL: `${callbackUrl}/auth/outlook/login/callback`,
    })).forRoutes(
      { path: '/auth/outlook/login', method: RequestMethod.GET },
      { path: '/auth/outlook/login/callback', method: RequestMethod.GET },
    )
  }
```

> {"error":{"code":"InvalidMsaTicket","message":"ErrorCode:
>   'PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND'. Message: ' Internal error:
>   spRPSTicket->ProcessToken failed. Failed to call
>   CRPSDataCryptImpl::UnpackData: Internal error: Failed to decrypt data.
>   :Failed to get session key. RecipientId=293577. spCache->GetCacheItem
>   returns error.:Cert Name: (null). SKI:
>   45237f1479435b9c4def8b7a1b36edb0105e0546...'","innerError":{"requestId":"4ea03cf1-79f8-421f-a0eb-d5bc6560da6a","date":"2019-07-05T08:44:20"}}}

Did I missed anything in the azure app registration config ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set up `passport.use(new OutlookStrategy({}))` in main function with providing there clientID and clientSecret?

Comment: Yep doing that,
````export class OutlookStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'outlook') {
  constructor(
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
  ) {
    super({
      clientID: config.get('OUTLOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
      clientSecret: config.get('OUTLOOK_SECRET'),
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
    passport.use(this);
  }
````
In the above code **passport.use(this);**

Comment: Hm, then I can't answer why is this happening. Try to debug it step by step starting with  printing credentials in the constructor to be sure that they are provided

Comment: It goes to outlook consent , where I gave allow access and all. But the issue happens in callback. will debug. Thanks :)